# Difference between original working tree and cloned working tree

Tags: git

What is the real difference between a set of files that was used to create (init) a git repository  (original working tree) and a cloned one ?

I mean, I guess that Git stores files in a different way in its database, so the original files that was used to create the repository are not useful once the repository is created.

Is it possible to stop tracking the original files and delete them ?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Could you describe your setup and workflow? -- Files can be *ignored* or *excluded* from Git, this could make a potential difference.

Comment: To sum up, are original files used to create a git repository useful after the creation as Git stores them in a different way in its databse (I guess) ?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for a *bare repository*? That's the one that has the "Git database" but not the files.

Comment: Exactly, I think bare repository is what I had in mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to store a Git repository without a working copy -- this is called a *bare repository*. Create one with `git init --bare`, add it as a remote or simply push to it from your working tree:

```
git push --all /path/to/bare/repo
```